# Calculate VWAP using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java

I have this Java code which I would like to rewrite to JavaScript:

```
package example;

import java.util.List;

public class Tain {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    private class PriceData {

        private double volume;
        private double price;

        public double getVolume() {
            return volume;
        }

        public void setVolume(double volume) {
            this.volume = volume;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
    }

    private double calculateBaseValueVwap(List<PriceData> side, double positionStep) {
        double cumSum = 0d;
        double totalVolume = 0d;
        double amountLeft = positionStep;
        for(PriceData level : side) {
            if(totalVolume >= positionStep || amountLeft <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            double amountForPriceLevel = 0d;
            if(amountLeft > level.getVolume()) {
                amountForPriceLevel = level.getVolume();
                cumSum += level.getPrice() * level.getVolume();
                totalVolume += level.getVolume();
            }
            else {
                amountForPriceLevel = level.getVolume() - amountLeft;
                cumSum += level.getPrice() * amountForPriceLevel;
                totalVolume += amountForPriceLevel;
            }
            amountLeft -= amountForPriceLevel;
        }
        return cumSum / totalVolume;
    }

}
```

I tried this:

```
class Tain
{
    static
    main(args)
    {}
    class PriceData
    {
        #volume = 0.0;
        #price = 0.0;
        getVolume()
        {
            return this.#volume;
        }
        setVolume(volume)
        {
            this.volume = volume;
        }
        getPrice()
        {
            return this.#price;
        }
        setPrice(price)
        {
            this.price = price;
        }
    }
    calculateBaseValueVwap(side, positionStep)
    {
        var cumSum = 0.0;
        var totalVolume = 0.0;
        var amountLeft = positionStep;
        for (const level of side)
        {
            if (totalVolume >= positionStep || amountLeft <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            var amountForPriceLevel = 0.0;
            if (amountLeft > level.getVolume())
            {
                amountForPriceLevel = level.getVolume();
                cumSum += level.getPrice() * level.getVolume();
                totalVolume += level.getVolume();
            }
            else
            {
                amountForPriceLevel = level.getVolume() - amountLeft;
                cumSum += level.getPrice() * amountForPriceLevel;
                totalVolume += amountForPriceLevel;
            }
            amountLeft -= amountForPriceLevel;
        }
        return cumSum / totalVolume;
    }
}
Tain.main([]);
```

It's not clear to me how to rewrite the Java Object `PriceData` and send it as a list in JavaScript. Can you guide me what is the proper way to implement this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your problem has to do with the definition of `PriceData` as an inner class of `Tain`. AFAIK there is not a clear, if possible, way to define a nested class even in modern Javascript versions.

As pointed out as well in other answers for the same reason, you can create an independent `PriceData` class: honestly I think it will be the best option.

As an alternative, another approach you could try would be defining `PriceData` as `static`. Please, see the following code:

```js
class Tain
{
    static main(args) {}
    
    static PriceData = class {
        #volume = 0.0;
        #price = 0.0;
        getVolume(){
            return this.#volume;
        }
        setVolume(volume){
            this.volume = volume;
        }
        getPrice(){
            return this.#price;
        }
        setPrice(price){
            this.price = price;
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

It will allow you to use `PriceData` like this:

```js
const pa = new Tain.PriceData();
pa.setPrice(12.4);
pa.setVolume(200);
const pb = new Tain.PriceData();
pb.setPrice(20.4);
pb.setVolume(100);
```

In Javascript there is not an explicit concept for `List` like in Java, you need to create an array that will contain these objects to pass that information to the `main` method:

```js
const prices = [pa, pb];
```

Then you can test your `Tain` `main` method with something like - I assume, as it is unclear in the question:

```js
Tain.main(prices, 100);
```

Please, pay attention to the definition of `static` methods in Javascript, they are conceived to handle stuff that, although defined in a class, it is not directly related to instances of that class. I am saying this because, if, for instance, in your `main` method you are supposed to use `calculateBaseValueVwap` then a better approach will be to directly define `calculateBaseValueVwap` as `static` instead and use just that method. In Java you can define a `static` `main` method that will be used to run your application, in Javascript there is not such a need.

Although you can certainly use classes for this task, one simpler approach could be the use of functions.

Let's first define `Tain`:

```js
Tain = function() {

    this.calculateBaseValueVwap = function(side, positionStep) {
        let cumSum = 0.0;
        let totalVolume = 0.0;
        let amountLeft = positionStep;
        for (let i = 0; i < side.length; i++) {  
            level = side[i];
            if(totalVolume >= positionStep || amountLeft <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            let amountForPriceLevel = 0.0;
            if(amountLeft > level.volume) {
                amountForPriceLevel = level.volume;
                cumSum += level.price * level.volume;
                totalVolume += level.volume;
            }
            else {
                amountForPriceLevel = level.volume - amountLeft;
                cumSum += level.price * amountForPriceLevel;
                totalVolume += amountForPriceLevel;
            }
            amountLeft -= amountForPriceLevel;
        }
        return cumSum / totalVolume;
    }
}
```

In order to being able to access `PriceData`, you can create a kind of *class* level function to represent that concept, for instance:

```js
Tain.PriceData = function(volume, price) {
    this.volume = volume;
    this.price = price;
}
```

You can define getters and setters for the `volume` and `price` properties if required.

Please, be aware that if you could define `PriceData` as an independent function as well; you could even do not use a function to represent that concept but simple Javascript objects:

```js
{
  price: 12.4,
  volume: 200
}
```

As stated before, it is unclear in your Java code how the `main` method is implemented but, for testing purposes, let's assume something like this:

```js
Tain.main = function(side, positionStep) {
    const tain = new Tain();
    const baseValueVwap = tain.calculateBaseValueVwap(side, positionStep);
    console.log(`Base value vwap: ${baseValueVwap}`);
    return baseValueVwap;
}
```

Then, test the code in a similar way as defined above:

```js
const pa = new Tain.PriceData(12.4, 200);
const pb = new Tain.PriceData(20.4, 100);
// Or, using directly objects
// const pa = { price: 12.4,  volume: 200 };
// const pb = { price: 20.4,  volume: 100 };

const prices = [pa, pb];
Tain.main(prices, 100);
```

The code could be improved with ES6 syntax and for sure in many ways, but it should work correctly.

If you have the opportunity, my advice would be using Javascript object notation for representing the `PriceData` and a single, independent function, `calculateBaseValueVwap`, defined somewhere - your HTML pages, your Javascript module, etcetera - that will be invoked directly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't actually that much wrong with your code. You're simply nesting a class inside a class, which ES6 does not permit, and you have an extra ending curly brace.

```js
class Tain {
    static main(args) {}
}

class PriceData {
    #volume = 0.0;
    #price = 0.0;
    getVolume() {
        return this.#volume;
    }
    setVolume(volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }
    getPrice() {
        return this.#price;
    }
    setPrice(price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    calculateBaseValueVwap(side, positionStep) {
        var cumSum = 0.0;
        var totalVolume = 0.0;
        var amountLeft = positionStep;
        for (const level of side) {
            if (totalVolume >= positionStep || amountLeft <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            var amountForPriceLevel = 0.0;
            if (amountLeft > level.getVolume()) {
                amountForPriceLevel = level.getVolume();
                cumSum += level.getPrice() * level.getVolume();
                totalVolume += level.getVolume();
            } else {
                amountForPriceLevel = level.getVolume() - amountLeft;
                cumSum += level.getPrice() * amountForPriceLevel;
                totalVolume += amountForPriceLevel;
            }
            amountLeft -= amountForPriceLevel;
        }
        return cumSum / totalVolume;
    }
}


Tain.main([]);
```